# Distributed Foto / Asset Management Software

Tags: cross-platform, digital-asset-management

I have a very niche problem. I have a lot of devices, with a lot of pictures. Before I really understood computers etc, I basically uploaded pictures to where ever I saw fit, Dropbox, Google Fotos, iCloud, I stored them scattered on like 10 different devices, copied them between them and now I want to consolidate them.

The issue I have is that the images are sometimes in different quality stored across services and devices and I fear that consolidating them with a "normal" software could lead to many duplicates of the same image.

I'm looking for a program that is *open source* and that I can run on a NAS or server. (I have both a Truenas as well as a Nextcloud running on which I could put this application)

**My wish list for this program would be the following:**

1. Pull new Images from my devices when in the same network.
2. I would like to have the ability to decide how the synchronization of collections of data works.
3. Stream the images of the "master database" to the device when in the same network. (So the images appear in a photo viewer / client of the device.)
4. The Server for the master database which controls the synchronization should ideally run on Linux or in a Docker container. However Windows or Mac would also be possible but they would require me to spin up a new server. (And I'd rather not have another server running)
5. Ideally there should exist a client which is compatible across Linux, MacOS, Windows, Android and iOS.
6. I'd like to be able to create subsets of the master database for which I can control the synchronization separately as well as being able to create those without any significant data overhead. (So I don't have to copy the images to a new directory and then just sync that one instead of the main one.)
7. The software should be able to detect identical images with lower quality (based on attributes like date and location when it was taken or the image itself) and if no more information is given keep the higher quality one and discard the lower quality one.

**And to expand on point 2:**

I'd like to have multiple options for synchronization:
In general all images should be uploaded to the master database into one set of images which are stored chronologically. However this master database is then not synchronized down to the clients so the clients don't all each have a copy of the master database.

I want to be able to create subsets of images for which I can control the behavior of the synchronization when an images is added, deleted or modified.
For example I would like to have a set of images that is shared across multiple devices such that adding of images is then propagated to every device which has this collection stored but the deletion of this image on one of the devices doesn't delete it for every other device who has this collection.
Then I would want there to be collections which are shared identically on many devices so, delete, modify and add are propagated on every device.

Basically I want to be able to create every permutation of one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many as well as add, modify and delete for a set of images.

So far I've looked at the following:

**Google Fotos:**
Has only one synchronization option but is otherwise a very good app and shared across many platforms. In addition I'd have to pay for the subscription and it is not local to my server.

**Apple Fotos:**
Only supports a master database shared across all devices, is not local and on my NAS, I need to pay for a subscription, isn't compatible with all devices.

**Nextcloud:**
It fails somewhat on point 2 and 3 in that it offers more control but not everything I want and it is a little cumbersome. In addition, the streaming works more or less depending on the servers power. The biggest downside is the data overhead. You cannot have images in different collections, you need to create a new folder with a new copy if you want to be to synchronize only a collection.

**Digicam:**
Only is capable of creating sets and collections without generating more data.

I very much doubt that such a program exists yet I'm open to being surprised.

Alternatively, I could try to write my own program that does all of that or maybe write a plugin for Nextcloud that expands on its abilities.

Thank you for your suggestions.

AliSot2000